# multiple validation on a single jTextfields and move to next text field after validation

Tags: java, swing

I am working on an Student Management application, its a window application in Swing , and in a frame I have to validate the multiple fields.

For each field I have to validate  that field is is blank or not, also data entered is in particular format like only Characters are allowed etc.

Please help and show example if possible.

Comment: welcome on this forum, but this question ins't answerable in this form, sorry ... please to read [Frequently Asked Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: and when does this validation happen? and +1 with mKorbel, please try to update your question with relevant information and let us know what have you tried

Answer (score 2):

- basically there are three ways for [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)

  1. let's validate as user action, use `JButton` for that
  2. use `DocumentListener` and/(or with) `DocumentFilter`
  3. use `InputVerifier`, `InputMask`
- or to use `InputVerifier`, `InputMask`, `Formatter` for [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)

Comment: could you put an example for Two text field with two validation on each.

Comment: @Ajay Kashyap `1.` read FAQ, `2.` linked tutorials contains examples or desciptions about all points from my sterille answer, `3.` [here is rest to the Oracle tutorials](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/CatalogJava.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You should use JFrame or JDialog to show a screen. 
1. Use JTextField for input value.
2. Implement ActionListener interface and use actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) method to check blank.